# How to remove default approval workflow email that notifies when an approval workflow has started and completed?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have been asked to remove default approval email when OOTB default workflows are sent when a workflow has started and completed.
How do you remove them?
I have checked under both "change the behavior of a single task" and "change the behavior of the overall task process" and I do not see a reference to the task "started" or completed" emails.

And if they can't be removed, is there a way to direct the email elsewhere?

This applies to SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer following steps :

1. Click on change behavior of the overall task process
   [image]
2. Under '**When task process starts**' there is one Email action (refer below)

   **Remove this email action**

[image]

3. Re-Publish the workflow
4. Done

Comment: Thank you please tell me though were to remove the :Completed"? Thank you.